# Отмена действия

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ui

Доброго времени суток.

Есть задача: возможность отмены собственных действий на сайте/форуме, например удалил сообщение/коммент(не смотря на предварительно подтверждёный вопрос подтверждения) и пожалел о содеяном, тогда подобная функция отмены будет очень кстати.

На данном ресурсе есть возможность отмены голоса ЗА и/или ПРОТИВ, которая достаточно полезна.

Собственно вопрос: как реализовывать подобный функционал? Когда выполнять запрос удаления записи(или любой другой операции) из базы? Или просто помечать запись определённым флагом "deleted"?

Какой метод решения является самым оптимальным? Просто придумать какой-нибудь велосипедо-костыль не составит труда, хотелось бы всё сделать правильно.

Буду рад словесному описанию алгоритмов или ссылок на чтиво касающегося данной темы. Зарание благодарю.

**UPD:** ответ тов. [[@wind](/users/4863/wind)](/users/4863/wind) хорош, но хотелось бы узнать по данной теме по-больше

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для реализации отмены каких-либо действий однозначно нужно их где-то хранить, чтобы иметь возможность откатиться к прежней версии или восстановить удаленное. И так как мы говорим о веб-разработке, то у нас как обычно встает два варианта: клиент и сервер. Но выдумывать хранение данной информации на клиенте в куках или прям на странице или хз где еще, как по мне, как раз описанный вами "велик" (еще и не "секьюрно"). Следовательно нужно хранить на сервере, а раз мы выбираем сервер, то почему бы не юзать ту же БД, в которой итак все хранится. Поэтому я считаю, что оптимально использовать именно схему "с флагами в БД". Судя по вопросу вы вкурсе, как ее реализовать, да это и вовсе не сложно.

Единственное, что хочу еще добавить, так это версионность, которая, как пример, реализована при редактировании вопросов на данном форуме. То есть можно в БД не только помечать запись какую-либо, как удаленную, а реализовать некую структуру для хранения версий постов, комментариев и тд. Имея данную структуру в БД, можно отменить не только одно действие, а вернуться к любому предыдущему, но это уже во многом зависит от задачи, нужно ли оно вообще вам или достаточно всего лишь отмены удаления.

К тому же, если рассматривать какую-либо соц. сеть, то при удалении например профайла юзера, насколько я знаю, опять же используется данная схема, ну и было бы странно, если удалив юзера, со всего портала пропала оставленная им информация, хотя иногда это требуется по ТЗ и тогда "каскады" в БД или ОРМ сама подчистит все связанные с сущностью данные.

Comment: спасибо, но вы своим вторым абзацом добавили мне немало работы=)

Comment: Обычно версионность нужна крайне редко.
То есть либо, в виде компромисса, хранить предыдущую версию вместе с текущей, либо же просто лог правок иметь.

Так что рекомендую как следует подумать, прежде, чем выполнять второй абзац, там действительно много работы ;)

Comment: возможно оставлю это для темы следующего вопроса

Comment: Рад, что мои ответ был вам полезен, а насчет версионности конечно да, работы добавится, но если вам оно не нужно то и не стоит заморачиваться, если вы твердо решили сделать, то не так уж и много работы с учетом реализованного уже ДАЛа и использования в системе ОРМ.

Answer (score 1):

Хранить в сессии историю команд. Интерфейс команды должен иметь методы Undo и Redo.

Comment: да, у меня тоже была идея с некторым стеком из делегатов